# At least one checkbox must be check inside every div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Html code

```
<div class="answer">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div class="answer">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<button>check</button>
```

jQuery Code

```
$('button').click(function(){

    var checkedboxes = $('.answer :checkbox:checked').length;

    if (checkedboxes === 0){
        alert('At least 1 checkbox must be checked from this div!');
    }
});
```

But my code not check at least one checkbox check inside every `<div class='answer'>`

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f8UhA/39/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
if ($('.answer').filter(function(){  return $(this).find(':checked').length === 0 }).length > 0 ) {
 alert('At least 1 checkbox must be checked from this div!');
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/f8UhA/40/)

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through all the `.answer` and check if there's no checkbox has been checked inside it:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.answer').each(function() {
        if($(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length === 0) {
            alert('At least 1 checkbox must be checked from this div!');
        }
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f8UhA/41/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.answer').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).find('input:checked').length ) {alert('At least 1 checkbox must be checked from this div!');
        return false;
}});});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Euhdf/)**

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your selector is that you select all answers `.answers`.
To select the problematic block, without looping all answers, there is a bit more complicated selector:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  // check if there is an '.answer' which does NOT have checked checkbox.
  var checkedboxes = $(".answer:not(:has(> input:checkbox:checked))").length;

    if (checkedboxes > 0){
        alert('At least 1 checkbox must be checked from this div!');
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f8UhA/45/)